# Should Social Media Icons Hold Present Color Value?

Tags: icons, social-media

When designing a website should social media icons keep their established color value or can they be restyled to associate with your website's theme?

Can changing the icon colors impact the user?

[image: Smashing Magazine using established color values] **VS** [image: Codrops website color values used rather than established icon colors]